# Joining two pandas DataFrames having same start and end date with missing values in one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrame objects `df1` and `df2`, both containing data from the same start and end date. `df1` has a total of 17376 rows. Each `date` has 48 rows (2 values per hour at timestamp xx:00 and xx:30) and there is a total of 362 days (Refer image link below). `df2` is a larger DataFrame with 144 rows per day (6 values per hour - xx:00, xx:10, xx:20, xx:30, xx:40, xx:50).(image link below)

[image: DateTime Organization of df1]

[image: DateTime Organization of df2]

I want to join df1 and df2 such that they have an exact matching date and time stamps and the same number of rows (dropping certain rows in df2). Ideally, all values corresponding to `df1` must be present in `df2`, but there are some missing values in between and they are unknown.

I want to merge `df1` and `df2` and also deal with the missing values. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello. Welcome to the community. We will really appreciate if you can please show the dataframe and also the whole problem along with your try in a proper way. The way you posted, it is very difficult to copy and run a test by others. So please go through this carefully [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the description, I would suggest using **[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)** or **[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)**. Here is a test example:

```
import pandas as pd

#generating test data
index1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='D')
index2 = pd.date_range('1/4/2000', periods=9, freq='D')
series = range(9)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([index1,series]).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame([index2,series]).T
df1.columns = ['Time','Data']
df2.columns = ['Time','Data']
```

**df1**:

```
                  Time Data
0  2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
1  2000-01-02 00:00:00    1
2  2000-01-03 00:00:00    2
3  2000-01-04 00:00:00    3
4  2000-01-05 00:00:00    4
5  2000-01-06 00:00:00    5
6  2000-01-07 00:00:00    6
7  2000-01-08 00:00:00    7
8  2000-01-09 00:00:00    8
```

**df2**:

```
                  Time Data
0  2000-01-04 00:00:00    0
1  2000-01-05 00:00:00    1
2  2000-01-06 00:00:00    2
3  2000-01-07 00:00:00    3
4  2000-01-08 00:00:00    4
5  2000-01-09 00:00:00    5
6  2000-01-10 00:00:00    6
7  2000-01-11 00:00:00    7
8  2000-01-12 00:00:00    8
```

Notice that data is available for different dates in both the dataframes.

```
#convert Time to pandas datetime format
#df1['Time'].to_datetime(df1['Time']) # <- uncomment this for your case
#df1['Time'].to_datetime(df1['Time'])  # <- uncomment this for your case

#making the time the index of the dataframes
df1.set_index(['Time'],inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['Time'],inplace=True)

#concatenating the dataframe column wise (axis=1)
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
print(df3)
```

**Output**:

```
           Data Data
Time                
2000-01-01    0  NaN
2000-01-02    1  NaN
2000-01-03    2  NaN
2000-01-04    3    0
2000-01-05    4    1
2000-01-06    5    2
2000-01-07    6    3
2000-01-08    7    4
2000-01-09    8    5
2000-01-10  NaN    6
2000-01-11  NaN    7
2000-01-12  NaN    8
```

**Taking care of Missing values**:

[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) correctly merges the data as per the data. `NaN`  indicate the missing values after combining, which can be handled mainly with  [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)(**filling** something inplace of `NaN`) or [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) (**dropping** the data containing `NaN`). Here is an example of `fillna` (`dropna` is used exactly the same way but without `0`) :

```
#filling 0's inplace of `NaN`. You can use also method='bfill' or 'ffill' or interpolate
df3 = df3.fillna(0,inplace=True) 
#df3 = df3.fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True) # <- uncomment if you want to use this
#df3 = df3.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True) # <- uncomment if you want to use this
```

**Output**:

```
             Data  Data
Time                  
2000-01-01     0     0
2000-01-02     1     0
2000-01-03     2     0
2000-01-04     3     0
2000-01-05     4     1
2000-01-06     5     2
2000-01-07     6     3
2000-01-08     7     4
2000-01-09     8     5
2000-01-10     0     6
2000-01-11     0     7
2000-01-12     0     8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added a new column in both the dataframes with the same name 'DateTime' and used df1.merge(df2, on = 'DateTime')

Comment: Merge/join works as well. It is usually handy to convert time to datetime object and index when working with time-series. If this answer helped you, you can upvote/accept it. So that other people know it works.